# svg #document load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have SVG in data attributes of an `<object>`:

```
<html:figure id="imapc">
    <html:object type="image/svg+xml" id="imap"></html:object>
</html:figure>
```

I am dynamically change the source of the data attribute:

```
this.svgobject = document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0];
this.svgobject.setAttribute("data", "lib/img/" + this.hash + ".svg");
```

When I try to get SVG DOM:

```
if("contentDocument" in this.svgobject) {
    this.svgdom = this.svgobject.contentDocument;
}
```

I get DOM like this

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Because `this.svgobject` hasn't loaded own DOM yet, but if `setTimeout` for `if ("contentDocument" in this.svgobject)` for `100ms` I get normally `this.svgdom`

```
<svg>...</svg>
```

Is there any "loaded" event for this SVG DOM waiting?

Comment: Yes there is an onload attribute available on `<object>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with onload function.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onload='init(evt)'>
  <html:figure id="imapc">
      <html:object type="image/svg+xml" id="imap"></html:object>
  </html:figure>
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
    function init(evt) {
      alert('svg is ready');
      console.log('ready');
      var svgobject = document.getElementById("imap");
      svgobject.setAttribute("data", "lib/img/" + this.hash + ".svg");
    }
  </script>
</svg>
```